# Parse.com Save Object Error

Tags: edit, profile, parse-platform

Running into issues when trying to edit an object in Javascript.

Getting a "Error 201: must have user password."

Tried to get the users password and couldn't succeed. Trying to edit the users username in my application

function editProfile() {

```
        Parse.initialize("", "");

        var ProfileEdit = Parse.Object.extend("User");
        var profile = new ProfileEdit();

        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

        profile.save(null, {
            success: function(profile) {
                profile.set(currentUser, $("editprofile-username"));
                profile.save();
            },

            error: function(user, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do something like the code I wrote, however I don't understand why are you are using save() two times, maybe I am not really getting the question. . .

```
function editProfile() {

    Parse.initialize("", "");

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    currentUser.set("username",$("editprofile-username"))
    currentUser.save(null, {
        success: function(user) {              

        },

        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
   });
}
```